# Grab values from html c# Datatable Row and Post them outside iframe

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, post, razor, datatable

Hello everyone I'm using a asp.net mvc enviroment to develope a small website were I render a datatable on an iframe which receives parameters from a FormCollection on the View where it's located (the iframe) so it refreshes on each submit post.

Anyway on each ROW that is shown on the table at the last column there's a buttom

```
                    <div class="row">
                        <!-- Table -->
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <div class="table-striped">
                                <table class="table table-bordered" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
                                    <thead align="center">
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>No.</th>
                                            <th>ID</th>
                                            <th>Pick</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody id="mydataTable">
                                        @{
                                            foreach (System.Data.DataRow dr in dt_ICCSSC.Rows)
                                            {
                                                string num_operacion = dr["num-op"].ToString();
                                                string cust_id = dr["id"].ToString();
                                                string name = dr["name"].ToString();

                                                <tr>
                                                    <td align="center">@num_op</td>
                                                    <td>@cust_id - @name</td>
                                                    @using (Html.BeginForm("MyView", "MyController", FormMethod.Post, new { target = "_top" }))
                                                    {
                                                    <td align="center">
                                                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Pick</button>
                                                    </td>
                                                    }
                                                </tr>

                                            }
                                        }
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </div>


                        </div>

                    </div>
```

And this Datatable comes from

```
    @model Project.Models.MyModels
    @{
        System.Data.DataSet ds_IIICCC = Model.cargar();
        System.Data.DataTable dt_ICCSSCX = ds_IIICCC.Tables[2];
        System.Data.DataTable dt_dt_ICCSSC = ds_IIICCC.Tables[1];
     }
```

So how can I grab the tr inside the td of the tbody of the table I created with razor syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this: 
https://dotnetfiddle.net/GJRsag

Comment: Or it's better to just do a get request instead of posting in a form, like this: https://dotnetfiddle.net/eQMp3c

Comment: Yes the first one worked perfectly, since I'm doing this in an iframe i need to post it although I just found a way to do my task with ajax thanks for the answer it really taught me something new :)